# Get checked items button listview in fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a fragment,where I can get checked items by clicking on them.The question is, how can I make this with button like "Get items". I am not sure if setOnItemClickListener will be good, because I will need OnClick.
My code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fcaffes,container,false);
    final ListView list=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,items);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    list.setItemChecked(4, true);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {//arg2-position,
              if(arg2==1) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Second argument was choosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
           if(arg2==0) {
             Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "First argument was choosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
           if(arg2==3) {
             Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Third argument was choosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
           if(arg2==4) {
             Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Fourth argument was choosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can used the custom list view.Create the layout and according to your requirement and get all values on getview method.please check this link:-
http://www.androprogrammer.com/2013/10/list-view-with-check-box-using-custom.html